# JQuery - how to edit the value of elements of a Cloned object?

Tags: jquery

Here's my HTML.  Apologies for formatting - this is my  first-ever question!

```
<div id="Template">
                    <table cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                       <tr valign="top">
                                <td> 
                                    <span class="Name" ></span>
                                    (<span class="Id"></span>)

                                        <span class="Addr" ></span><br>
                                        <span class="City" ></span>,&nbsp;
                                        <span class="State" ></span>&nbsp;
                                        <span class="Zip" ></span><br>
                                </td>
                     </tr>

                    </table>
```

---

Here's my JQuery so far:

```
$.getJSON(serverURL,{  id: X  },
        function(data) {

          $.each(data, function(key,val){
               var clonedDiv= $('#Template').clone();

              //"Each" below represents the various data members of the object currently being processed.
              $.each(val,function(key2,value){

                  //Below are the only Keys needed so skip the rest.
                  if (key2=='Id' || key2=='Name' || key2=='Addr' || key2=='City' || key2=='State' || key2=='Zip'){
                      alert('Key2:'+key2+' val2:'+JSON.stringify(value));
                ///INSERT VALUE INTO NEWLY-CLONED DIV SPAN CHILD HERE???      
                  }

              });
              $('#TemplatePrev').append(clonedDiv);
          });
        })
.success(function() { 
    alert('success'); 
})
.error(function() { alert('error'); })
.complete(function() { 
    //alert('complete'); 
});
```

When the above is run, there are 10 objects returned by the JSON call and the JQuery clones 10 DIVs that look like the #Template div.   However, I need to shove that JSON Stringified value into each span dynamically.   Any idea how to do this?   I've been at this for 2 hours before breaking down and posting here.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's usually a recommendable practice to have a single id in an HTML document, in your case, you'll end up with 10 `#Template`, use class instead for your own good :)

Comment: yes, definitely.  I will dynamically assign a number to the end of that "Template" so that I generate 10 unique ID values.   Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
if (key2=='Id' || key2=='Name' || key2=='Addr' || key2=='City' || key2=='State' || key2=='Zip'){                  
   clonedDiv.find('.' + key2).text(JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
clonedDiv.find('span.'+key2).text(JSON.stringify(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution is to use a templating solution that does this for you. A couple that come to mind are [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [Pure](http://beebole.com/pure/), or [Underscore Templates](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template).

Otherwise something like this should work:

`clonedDiv.find("." + key2).text(value)`

Also @andreas was right about copying the id, try to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks - this works too!   I am trying to Vote Up...but it "requires 15 reputation".   Me==newb.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
   makeClone();

});
function makeClone() {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var cloneing = $('.divclone').clone();
        $('#container').append(cloneing.removeClass().attr("id",'new'+i));
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="container" >
<div class="divclone">
this is it
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope can be done like this .now you have different ids for cloned div's and you can manipulate as yo wish.